# How to extract the weekday name (e.g., moday, tuesday) from a date in azure databricks SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I currently fail to extract the weekday name from a date using SQL in azure databricks.

I have the following:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-02 |
| 2023-01-03 |

And what I want as an output is:

| Date | Weekday |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Sunday |
| 2023-01-02 | Monday |
| 2023-01-03 | Tuesday |

I found the exrtract() or the weekday() functions which only give back an integer. Unfortunately datename() is not defined under Azure DB.
The only way I can think of would be to use a lenghty combination of case when and weekday() in which I would have to specify each weekday name separately.

Any help or pointing towards a more elegant solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date format function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format

With date format pattern E which is day of week https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern